# Can I say this about real countries in my fiction?

Tags: fiction, legal, setting

I am writing a visual novel and use a fictional country in "real-world" setting. Some cases have been bothering me and I'm not sure if it's legal to write this because it might be insulting(?):

1. To place my country I had to cut a part of China, so it is located between Russia, Mongolia and China.
2. I mention that my country's army has "some connections with Japan" and recruits children from there.
3. I mention that my country's army shoots up Mongolian illegal immigrants at the border.

Edit: To clarify, I do not have intentions of insulting countries, just want to write what would be suitable for my story and am afraid of law suits. 
Also I live in Russia.

Edit: I can rephrase the question so it will sound like this: Can I assign fictional slightly negative traits to countries from real world in my fictional world?

Comment: To clarify, that's a fictional country in a fictional world, the latter being in part inspired to the real world.

Comment: Are you using your fictional country to critique the real one? If so then someone is going to feel insulted. Not that it matters, it is your story... say what you want. Are you afraid of retribution? Law suits?

Comment: @rebusB I don't want to critique other countries, but yeah I'm afraid of law suits

Comment: If that is the case you may want to ask this on a legal advice site. Not a lawyer here but I believe if you are not lying than you cannot be found guilty of libel. Furthermore since this is a work of fiction you can say whatever you want, legally. I don't see a nation state suing an artist for something like this, but if they are thin skinned and feel threatened they may find other ways to make things difficult. Artists say critical things about nations and people all the time, some would say that is the purpose of art.

Comment: If you're asking about legal aspects, then you absolutely need to specify your real-world jurisdiction. Please [Edit] your question to incorporate that, and the other information you've added in the comments section, into the question itself.

Comment: @aCVn Sorry, but what do you mean by my real-world jurisdiction? What exactly do I need to specify?

Comment: @sunDalik "Real world jurisdiction" means where in the world do you live. :) Also, it isn't illegal to offend people. It might be unethical, but it's not illegal. So whether X is legal and whether it might offend someone are entirely separate questions.

Comment: Laws differ from place to place; certainly between countries (the US is not Germany is not Japan is not the UK is not South Korea is not Australia is not South Africa is not ... well, you get the idea), and sometimes within the same country (such as between states in the US). Unless you tell us where you are located (strictly speaking, which jurisdiction you're in), people would either (a) have to guess, or (b) answer based on *any possible* jurisdiction, which is overly broad. By giving this information, you are much more likely to get an answer that is useful *to you*.

Comment: "my country's army shoots up Mongolian illegal immigrants at the border" - how many illegal immigrants are we talking about here? Does your country just have a zero-tolerance policy to illegal immigration, or is it facing a horde comparable to the US/Mexico situation? Because if it's the latter, then considering Mongolia is the least densely populated country in the world, that would completely shatter my suspension of disbelief.

Comment: For the record, my suspension is disbelief is already begin stretched by the idea that Japan, a country with a notoriously declining birth rate, would let another country recruit its children for an army. I'm not putting any of this in an answer because it's nothing really to do with whether Mongolia or Japan would be upset by it; it just doesn't seem particularly plausible to me.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE sunDalik, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].

Answer (score 4):

Alternative history is a mainstay of speculative fiction.  Redrawing countries' borders is very often a part of that.  Sometimes countries that exist in the real world are missing.  Sometimes new countries are added.  Heck, even real history can make changes that dramatic in less than a decade.

You're asking a two-part question.  First, if it's okay to invent a country and stick it in land currently part of another country (in your case, China, and perhaps parts of Russia and Mongolia).  Second, if it's okay to give your invented country a personality and history and political actions.

The answer to both questions is yes.  It's done all the time.  Whether your story is a vision of the future as starting from our present or an alternative history set in the present day or past, or in the future with a different history today, it fits right into speculative fiction's boundaries.

It's possible some of your specifics might upset people to the point of taking legal action.  And I'm not familiar with Russian law.  While I doubt there's anything that would make your book illegal, I honestly have no idea if that's a risk.  In the United States, everything you mention is perfectly legal and rather mundane.  That may not be true elsewhere.

I was going to give you a short list of some books you might consider reading with similar aspects, starting with *[Ecotopia](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/550165.Ecotopia)*.  But it turns out there are hundreds.  So many that there's actually a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_country).  Many of the examples on that page are stories about hidden countries (like Oz) or completely fictional places that don't interact with the rest of the world.  But some are indeed about countries carved out of existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

Providing you live in a country with laws protecting freedom of expression and have fair libel laws, then you aren’t doing anything that can be considered illegal.

Could China be annoyed with your story and try to take legal action against you? 
Possibly, but unlikely.  But, as long as you stay out of China it wouldn’t amount to anything.

Could you annoy North Korea?  Very unlikely.  But, if you did, they have a history of hunting down and killing people that make them cross.  But, think how famous you’d become, and the risk is worth the reward.

Would Mongolia get annoyed you fictional murdered their citizenry?  Unlikely, they seem like a reasonable people living in a democratic parliamentary republic with an independent judiciary.

Comment: countries murder people across international borders ALL the time.  Kim Jung Un assassinated his half brother at a Malaysian airport just last year.